# How to push notification to mobile (Android)

Tags: android, odoo, odoo-mobile

I have a question about Push Notification,from odoo to android 
i want something like this 
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TDa8KLGQt2I

I am searching for information about custom push notification. I want to implement a tunnel between server(odoo) and devices (Android ). When it comes a time server should send information to device (App).